# Remove all special char except apostrophe

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a sentence, I want to count all the duplicated words:
It is an exercice from Exercism.io `Word count`

For example for the input `"olly olly in come free"`

`plain
olly: 2
in: 1
come: 1
free: 1`

**I have this test for exemple:**

```
  def test_with_quotations
    phrase = Phrase.new("Joe can't tell between 'large' and large.")
    counts = {"joe"=>1, "can't"=>1, "tell"=>1, "between"=>1, "large"=>2, "and"=>1}
    assert_equal counts, phrase.word_count
  end
```

**this is my method**

```
def word_count
    phrase = @phrase.downcase.split(/\W+/)
    counts = phrase.group_by{|word| word}.map {|k,v| [k, v.count]}
    Hash[*counts.flatten]
  end
```

For the test above I have this failure when I run it in the terminal:

```
  2) Failure:
PhraseTest#test_with_apostrophes [word_count_test.rb:69]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-{"first"=>1, "don't"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "then"=>1, "cry"=>1}
+{"first"=>1, "don"=>2, "t"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "then"=>1, "cry"=>1}
```

My problem is to remove all chars except `'`apostrophe...

the regex in the method almost works... 
`phrase = @phrase.downcase.split(/\W+/)`
but it remove the apostrophes...

I don't want to keep the single quote around a word, `'Hello'` => `Hello`
but `Don't be cruel` => `Don't` `be` `cruel`

Comment: try `/[^'a-z]/`

Comment: or try this: `/[a-z']+/i`

Comment: it keep the single quotes :( @dagw

Comment: neither @sagarpandya82

Comment: There seems to be some confusion, could you clarify your question a little. Maybe give a more thorough example.>>> Okay you've done that, can you now state the desired output for your second example?

Comment: I've edited all :)

Comment: You said, "problem is to remove all chars except 'apostrophe`". If the string were "don't go until it's over", that would leave a string containing two apostropes. You mean, "problem is to remove all chars except 'apostrophes` and ...", where you fill in the blanks. Distinguishing between single quotes and apostrophes is not easy (why oh why aren't they different characters?). For example, "who is the 'femme fatale' in Les' play?" or "'tis Les' play".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
string.scan(/\b[\w']+\b/i).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|a,(k,v)| k[a]+=1}
```

The regex employs word boundaries (\b).
The scan outputs an array of the found words and for each word in the array they are added to the hash, which has a default value of zero for each item which is then incremented.

Turns out my solution whilst finding all items and ignoring case will still leave the items in the case they were found in originally.
This would now be a decision for Nelly to either accept as is or to perform a downcase on the original string or the array item as it is added to the hash.

I'll leave that decision up to you :)

Comment: If `string = "'tis Les' play"`, your code would return `{"tis"=>1, "Les"=>1, "play"=>1}`, whereas the two apostrophes (not single quotes) should have been kept:  `{"'tis"=>1, "Les'"=>1, "play"=>1}`. This is not so much a criticism of your answer but a testament to the difficulty of distinguishing between single quotes and apostrophes.

Comment: That's perfect @grail, thanks for your help !!
Also thanks to everyone who tried to help :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland - not sure what type of keyboard you are on, but an apostrophe and a single quote on my keyboard are one and the same.  The only difference is for when they are used and how you would grammatically speak about them, ie when used in something like don't it is called an apostrophe but when used like so, 'here are some words' they are called single quotes as they are now quoting text.  Hence your example makes little sense.  What I would agree with is that by quoting the intention is to keep the words together, so you might expect {"tis Les"=>1, "play"=>1}

Comment: @grail, yes, I realize they are the same character, which is unfortunate for we coders. `"'tis Les' play"` contains one word, "'tis", that is a contraction that begins with an apostrophe, and another, `"Les'"`, that is the possessive form of `Les"`, the apostrophe being at the end because the word ends with an `"s"`. My point is simply that It would be a challenge for software to determine that both words contain an apostrophe rather than "tis Les"` constituting an expression that is surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - ahh, that makes much more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
irb(main):015:0> phrase
=> "First: don't laugh. Then: don't cry."
```

Try:

```
irb(main):011:0> Hash[phrase.downcase.scan(/[a-z']+/)
                     .group_by{|word| word.downcase}
                     .map{|word, words|[word, words.size]}
                    ]
=> {"first"=>1, "don't"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "then"=>1, "cry"=>1}
```

---

With your update, if you want to remove single quotes, do that first:

```
irb(main):038:0> p2
=> "Joe can't tell between 'large' and large."
irb(main):039:0> p2.gsub(/(?<!\w)'|'(?!\w)/,'')
=> "Joe can't tell between large and large."
```

Then use the same method.

But you say -- `gsub(/(?<!\w)'|'(?!\w)/,'')`  will remove the apostrophe in `'Twas the night before.` Which I reply you will eventually need to build a parser that can determine the distinction between an apostrophe and a single quote if `/(?<!\w)'|'(?!\w)/` is not sufficient.

You can also use word boundaries:

```
irb(main):041:0> Hash[p2.downcase.scan(/\b[a-z']+\b/)
                  .group_by{|word| word.downcase}
                  .map{|word, words|[word, words.size]}
                 ]
=> {"joe"=>1, "can't"=>1, "tell"=>1, "between"=>1, "large"=>2, "and"=>1}
```

But that does not solve `'Tis the night` either.

Comment: It keep the single quotes `' '`

Comment: But it meets requirements, TS does not mention he want to remove quotes too. @Nelly

Comment: @Nelly: You did not say that in your example. Keeping apostrophes yet removing single quotes is a tougher problem to solve with a regex alone.

Comment: @Nelly - I am confused??  In the question you say :- My problem is to remove all chars except 'apostrophe, but when presented a solution you say :- It keep the single quotes  .... which is it, do you want them or not??

Comment: I want to keep the appostrophe like here `Don't worry` and I want to remove the single quotes like  `'Hello everyone' `=> `Hello everyone` Sorry i wasn't clear...

Comment: Might pay to put a second example showing that, otherwise it gets confusing.  Just to be correct, you are saying that you have data that looks like ... str = "'Hello everyone'" ... If it is not clear that is a set of double quotes outside of single quotes around the words.  Here str will look like example above.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
str = "First: don't 'laugh'. Then: 'don't cry'."
reg = /
      [a-z]         #single letter
      [a-z']+       #one or more letters or apostrophe
      [a-z]         #single letter
      '?            #optional single apostrophe

      /ix           #case-insensitive and free-spacing regex

str.scan(reg).group_by(&:itself).transfor‌​m_values(&:count) 
  #=> {"First"=>1, "don't"=>2, "laugh"=>1, "Then"=>1, "cry'"=>1}
```

Comment: Still this may not work for certain conditions but it may be good enough for you.